# Multiple Issues with Picture Library

Tags: error, picture-library

I am facing following issues with Picture Library:

1. On one user, except adding him to the Full Control group, he is not
   able to see the new item or edit properties form. I tried from one
   other user's account and he can see the forms without being added in
   the Owners group.
2. Items uploaded by users are visible only from their own account.
   (Content Approval is not enabled)
3. I got an error (screenshot attached) when trying to edit, in spite
   of checking out  being disabled.

More Information:

- I have used Advanced Column Permissions, enabled Major Versions,
  enabled Content Type Management (to hide unwanted picture library
  fields like "Date Taken", etc.)
- I have not enabled Content Approval, Check Out before Editing.
- I have created workflows to send emails and Lookup details from other lists.

Please help me out on this!
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a required field on a new document (or picture) then it is checked out when it is initially uploaded. Check out is ALWAYS enabled, but you can FORCE check out to be used.

Further, until that document is checked in for the first time with the required metadata completed, **it will only be visible to the user who uploaded it**. Even having Site Collection admins can't see it until it is checked in for the first time.

Comment: That's Enlightening!! Library does have a required field for a column. Will try it out and revert back!. One more thing... How to force check out?

Comment: Can force checkout be achieved by SPD?

Comment: I think you can force check out on the versioning settings of the library